# d3 updating axis domain destroys labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, axis-labels

I am using the following code to rotate the text of my axis' labels:

```
graph.append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('dx', '-.8em')
    .attr('dy', '.15em')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-50),translate(10,10)')
```

Now I change the domain of the axis and want to update the screen like that:

```
x.domain([ parseDate(data[0].x), parseDate(newValDate)])
graph.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis)
```

After having done this, the axis looks like this:

[image]

Question: Why is this behavior occuring and how can I fix this?
Thanks :)

Edit (Concerning the comment to LarsKotthoff): This is the jump i mentioned:

[image]

Comment: You need to run the code to rotate the labels after each `.call(xAxis)`.

Comment: Why is it you set the attr class to `'x axis'` but when you select you have class: `.x.axis`?

Comment: @hasanovh because I have to tell d3 that I select by class and not by ID for example

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This works but not as beautiful as I wish ... I dont know why, but 2 out of 10 labels "jump" 10px up before they re getting redrawn correctly...

Comment: This might be an artifact of the transition.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix this?